# How to view all branches in a remote git repository

Tags: git-branch

git branch -a shows me all the branches PROVIDED I already have cloned the branch. For example if I have a remote branch that I have cloned, executing this from the base dir gives me this

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/xxx-3.5.x
  remotes/origin/xxx-3.6.0.x
  remotes/origin/xxx-4.x
  remotes/origin/xxx-publisher
  remotes/origin/xxx-sequencer
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/release/3.6.8
```

Now I want to get this info without having to clone the branch first. Is there a command that takes the url to the remote repo outputs the above info? If I execute this command outsire a git project dir,I get this

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /export)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote):

```
git ls-remote /url/of/an/upstream/repo
```

> Displays references available in a remote repository along with the associated commit IDs.

Those "references" include the branches (`refs/heads`) and the tags (`refs/tags`).
To see only the branches:

```
git ls-remote --heads /url/of/an/upstream/repo
```

In both cases, no clone is required.

Comment: Very nice. Solved my problem. Thanks very much